# Is there a reason why I can see my data frame in r studio but ggplot2 cannot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

A data frame I created from a csv I imported cannot be seen in ggplot2.
I inspected the frame and I am pretty sure it's there but I am new to R. This is a frame that appeared to work with every function but when it came to this one it stopped working.
This is my code:

```
    visualize(height_diff_under_null) +
      shade_p_value(obs_stat = obs_diff_position_height, direction = "both") +
      labs(x = "Difference in mean height for forwards and centers", y = "Count",
           title = "Null distribution of differences in forward and center height",
           subtitle = "Actual difference observed in the data is marked in red"
           )
```

[image]

Environment showing csv and the data frame:

[image]

After adding the code:

```
dput(head(height_diff_under_null, 20))
```

result:

```
structure(list(replicate = 1:20, stat = c(0.254006410256409, 
-0.362847222222229, -0.104166666666671, -0.0643696581196593, 
0.0152243589743648, 0.0550213675213627, -0.323050213675216, 0.114716880341874, 
0.0351228632478637, 0.174412393162399, 0.612179487179489, 0.174412393162399, 
-0.0444711538461604, -0.502136752136749, -0.00467414529914834, 
0.134615384615387, 0.0351228632478637, 0.492788461538467, -0.0842681623931583, 
-0.402644230769226)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("infer", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), response = height, explanatory = position, response_type = "numeric", explanatory_type = c(`explanatory_variable(x)` = "factor"), distr_param = c(df = 151.819892587405), null = "independence", theory_type = "Two sample t", generated = TRUE, type = "permute", hypothesized = TRUE, formula = height ~ 
    position, fitted = FALSE, stat = "diff in means")
```

So I tried to use that code and I'm not sure if I used it right

```
library(tidyverse)

height_diff_under_null %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = stat)) +
  geom_histogram(bins = 10) +

  visualize(height_diff_under_null) +
  shade_p_value(obs_stat = obs_diff_position_height, direction = "both") +
  labs(x = "Difference in mean height for forwards and centers", y = "Count",
       title = "Null distribution of differences in forward and center height",
       subtitle = "Actual difference observed in the data is marked in red"
       )
```

The result:

```
Error in `ggplot_add()`:
! Can't add `visualize(height_diff_under_null)` to a ggplot object.
Backtrace:
 1. ggplot2:::`+.gg`(...)
 2. ggplot2:::add_ggplot(e1, e2, e2name)
 4. ggplot2:::ggplot_add.default(object, p, objectname)
Error in ggplot_add(object, p, objectname) :
```

The error I received after adding to the top:

```
  height_diff_under_null %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = stat)) +
  geom_histogram(bins = 10) +

  visualize(height_diff_under_null) +
  shade_p_value(obs_stat = obs_diff_position_height, direction = "both") +
  labs(x = "Difference in mean height for forwards and centers", y = "Count",
       title = "Null distribution of differences in forward and center height",
       subtitle = "Actual difference observed in the data is marked in red"
       )
```

The error:

```
Error in `ggplot_add()`:
! Can't add `visualize(height_diff_under_null)` to a ggplot object.
Backtrace:
 1. ggplot2:::`+.gg`(...)
 2. ggplot2:::add_ggplot(e1, e2, e2name)
 4. ggplot2:::ggplot_add.default(object, p, objectname)
Error in ggplot_add(object, p, objectname) :
```

Pic of error:

[image]

After testing Mark's code:
[Mark's code in new file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWhjo.png)

Photos for Phil
[libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkXwj.png)
[Environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQEJO.png)

Comment: hi travis! please provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Hello Mark, the purpose is to get a p-value I can show you the code I based this on and what I did.   visualize(gpa_diff_under_null) +
  shade_p_value(obs_stat = obs_diff_gpa_sex, direction = "both") +
  labs(x = "Difference in mean GPA for females and males", y = "Count",
       title = "Null distribution of differences in female and male GPAs",
       subtitle = "Actual difference observed in the data is marked in red"
       )

Comment: I cant add a pic in here to sow you what the graph should look like, I've been at this for hours any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please put the code and the data in your question, not the comments Travis!

Comment: ```{r}
visualize(height_diff_under_null) +
  shade_p_value(obs_stat = position_height, direction = "both") +
  labs(x = "Difference in mean height for forwards and centers", y = "Count",
       title = "Null distribution of differences in forward and center height",
       subtitle = "Actual difference observed in the data is marked in red"
       )
```

Comment: This was the original csv: nba_center_forward and I created a new frame off of that position_height

Comment: once again, ***do not put the data or code in the comments***. Replace the photos in your question with the actual code and the actual data, enough that I can reproduce your problem on my pc.

Comment: Oh my bad I'll do it now

Comment: It's fixed and I added a pic of the original code

Comment: that is better, thank you for doing that. We now have the code, but not the data. Can you run `dput(head(height_diff_under_null, 20))` in your RStudio console and add the output to your question? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Mark, I ran the command and added the result.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide what packages you are calling. It's not clear to me where this `visualize()` function is coming from, and why you'd expect to work with other `ggplot2` code.

Comment: Hey Phill I added it in pictures